# vuetify checkbox внутри v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

В общем не пойму как выловить в v-select, что данный объект уже выбран. Вот код:

```
  <v-select
            v-model="selected"
            :items="items"
            item-value="id"
            return-object
            hide-details
            filled
            multiple
            :label="$t(name)"
        >
            <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
                <v-chip color="primary" label small>
                    <v-avatar v-if="item.icon" class="pr-2">
                        <img :src="item.icon" :alt="buildName(item)" />
                    </v-avatar>
                    <span>{{ buildName(item) }}</span>
                </v-chip>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        <v-simple-checkbox color="primary"></v-simple-checkbox>
                        <v-avatar v-if="item.icon" class="pr-2">
                            <img :src="item.icon" :alt="buildName(item)" />
                        </v-avatar>
                        <span>{{ buildName(item) }}</span>
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </template>
        </v-select>
```

Там, где v-simple-checkbox, не хватает переменной для v-model, к которой нужно привязаться, но понять, есть ли она вообще - не получается, кто знает, подскажите

Comment: Здравствуйте, в чем проблема? Не очень понимаю "выловить чекбокс".

Comment: @FeironoX5 как узнать что данный объект выбран, по какой переменной?